# Is there any difference in JSON Key when using single quote and double quote?

Tags: javascript, json, double-quotes

I ran two pieces of javascript codes in a online JS running platform:[Website Link](http://jsconsole.com/)

```
pets = '{'pet_names':[{"name":"jack"},{"name":"john"},{"name":"joe"}]}';
var arr = JSON.parse(pets);
alert(arr.pet_names[1].name);
```

Code with double quotes ("pet_names") would be OK but with single quotes('pet_names') would remind a error:**"Unexpected identifier"**

```
pets = '{"pet_names":[{"name":"jack"},{"name":"john"},{"name":"joe"}]}';
var arr = JSON.parse(pets);
alert(arr.pet_names[1].name);
```

So, why do it would happen?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In JSON only double quotes are valid.

You can find the standard on [JSON.org](http://json.org/)

> A value can be a string in ***double quotes***, or a number, or true or
>   false or null, or an object or an array. These structures can be
>   nested.

In other words, no strings in single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

The first one didn't work because you have a syntax error where you try to define your string literal
you probably wanted

```
pets = '{\'pet_names\':[{"name":"jack"},{"name":"john"},{"name":"joe"}]}';
```

notice the quotes are escaped.

Now if you used that string in the json parser you would still get an error(SyntaxError: Unexpected token ') because keys in JSON must be defined with double quotes, using single quotes is valid for defining JavaScript object literals which is separate from JSON.