# JQuery.parseJSON not working with string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, string, parsing

I am trying to parse a string into an object.
I have looked at the jQueryparseJSON documentation at the following [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)
I've also included the jquery library so I know it's not that.

This is my code so far

```
var str = "{'val1': 1, 'val2': 2, 'val3': 3}";
var obj = jQueryparseJSON( str );
alert(obj.val1);
```

In Firebug I am getting the following errors:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

I know the solution is more than likely very simple, but I have been repeatedly overlooking it.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24592841/is-there-any-difference-in-json-key-when-using-single-quote-and-double-quote

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The test string in your sample code is not valid JSON:

```
var str = '{"val1": 1, "val2": 2, "val3": 3}';
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( str );
alert(obj.val1);
```

Now, if you're doing all this because some service is making that object available as a JSON string, it's *probably* the case that jQuery will do the parsing step for you anyway. If you're just trying to include an object literal into your JavaScript code, then there's no reason to involve the JSON services at all:

```
var obj = { val1: 1, val2: 2, val3: 3 };
```

creates an object.

Note that JSON syntax is stricter than JavaScript object literal syntax.  JSON insists that property names be quoted with double-quote characters, and of course values can only be numbers, strings, booleans, or `null`.

Comment: but how can you add an element to your obj variable. for example val4: 4

Comment: @BlastFire `obj.val4 = 4;`

Answer (score 3):

Your string is not valid JSON. Object keys must be surrounded with double quotes, not single quotes.

```
var str = '{"val1": 1, "val2": 2, "val3": 3}';
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(str);
alert(obj.val1);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/PTkKR/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function str2json (str, val, obj) {
var obj = str.indexOf("'") != -1 
          ? JSON.parse(str.replace(/'/g, "\"")) 
          : JSON.parse(str);
    return (val === undefined ? obj /* JSON.stringify(obj) */ : obj[val])
};

str2json("{'val1': 1, 'val2': 2, 'val3': 3}", "val1"); // `1`

str2json("{'val1': 1, 'val2': 2, 'val3': 3}") 
// `obj` : `[object Object]` ,
// `JSON.stringify(obj)` : `{"val1":1,"val2":2,"val3":3}`
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/n8jLG/

Comment: This is going to cause problems when there are single quotes embedded within string values or in the keys themselves.

Comment: @cookiemonster Ok, good point. Should answer be withdrawn ? Or, try to fix by assessing quotes more thoroughly ? Where case `str`, or `var`, is actual string appearing as `arguments[0]` above ? Havnt viewed a `key` which included single quotes; example in the wild ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a `typo` error in your code :

here `var obj = jQueryparseJSON( str );`

should be `var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( str );`